# SCCM 2012 Create Application with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sccm

Does anybody have an idea on how to accomplish this task? 
I need the following information inside the application
Manufacturer:
Application Name:
Version:
Installationmedia path:
Install command:
Uninstall commmand:

I have found some examples: http://blog.lechar.nl/2012/04/03/creating-an-sccm-2012-application-with-powershell/
But I cannot get this working, does someone have a from scratch example on how to do this?
The example I found does not explain so much on how do i get the MSI file into the application, how do I get the AuthScopeID and so on? I would be very happy to see that someone with more knowledge in SCCM PowerShell than me maybe could rewrite this so it is ready to use but with my own parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Do you still need help with this? Basic premise is:

1. Import the sccm powershell module (Import-Module "\SERVERNAME\SMS_SITE\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1")
2. Then use New-CMApplication cmdlet
3. After that you use Add-CMDeploymentType to create the deployment type
4. Then create the deployment to a collection
5. Distribute content to the distribution points

That should give you a basic application, if you need anything more detailed let us know and we can work something out for you.

I tried to link you to each of the cmdlets but I dont have a high enough reputation yet so this is the main link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj821831(v=sc.20).aspx